# Android Broadcast how to send and receive list of object

Tags: java, android, list

I would like to refresh my ListView. In my service I'm prepare list of objects. How to send list of object and receive in ListView?

My service

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //populate list
    //send list
    sendLocationBroadcast(poiList);
}
 private void sendLocationBroadcast(List<Poi> poiList) {

        Intent locationIntent = new Intent();
        locationIntent.setAction(LOACTION_ACTION);
        locationIntent.putExtra(LOCATION_MESSAGE, poiList.toString());

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(locationIntent);

}
```

And main Activity

```
 @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            if (null != intent && intent.getAction().equals(LOACTION_ACTION)) {

                String locationData = intent.getStringExtra(LOCATION_MESSAGE);

                ArrayList<Poi> dataList = (ArrayList<Poi>) intent.getSerializableExtra("DATA_LIST");

            }

        }
```

How to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
locationIntent.putExtra(LOCATION_MESSAGE, poiList.toString());
```

to

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("data",poiList);
locationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

to read data

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("data")) {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null)
         ArrayList<Poi> dataList = (ArrayList<Venue>) bundle.getSerializable("arrayListVenue");
}
```

and make sure that you `implements Serializable` at your `Poi` object